# HTML5,draggable and contentEditable not working together

Tags: javascript, html

When a `draggable` attribute is enabled on a parent element(`<li>`) I cant make `contenteditable` work on its child element (`<a>`).

The focus goes on to child element (`<a>`),but I cant edit it at all.

Please check this sample

http://jsfiddle.net/pavank/4rdpV/11/

EDIT: I can edit content when I disable `draggable` on `<li>`

Comment: just reported a bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170139 will wait for the "official" response to see if this is a bug or an intentional behavior

Comment: The bug was just fixed in Blink! it already works in Chrome 29.0.1547.2 canary

Answer (score 8):

I came across the same problem today, and found a solution [using jQuery]

```
$('body').delegate('[contenteditable=true]','focus',function(){
    $(this).parents('[draggable=true]')
            .attr('data-draggableDisabled',1)
            .removeAttr('draggable');
    $(this).blur(function(){
        $(this).parents('[data-draggableDisabled="1"]')
                .attr('draggable','true')
                .removeAttr('data-draggableDisabled');
    });
});
```

`$('body')` can be replaced by anything more specific.

If new `contenteditable` elements are not added in the runtime, one can use `bind` instead of `delegate`.

Comment: When an element with `contentEditable` attribute gets focus this script removes `draggable` attributes from all its parents. And when the element loses focus `draggable` attributes are recovered. The idea is that the parent element will not be dragged if its child's content is being edited. As soon as user tries to drag the parent element, the `contentEditable` element will lose focus and `draggable` attribute will be recovered :)

Comment: @Vanwaril I added my own answer that uses raw HTML and javascript (since the jsfiddle has the framework option set to "No-Library (pure JS)"), and I just noticed you put a bounty on this question, and I don't really know how bounties work, so I thought I should let you know that I added an answer to this question.

Comment: Is there no non-hackish way?? :(

Comment: @Vanwaril I don't think so :/. I know the DOM can be a pain in the butt to deal with sometimes, and this is just one of those peculiarities. It might be a bug, but it's more likely intentional because maybe the browser can't handle being able to drag an element and edit it since it uses the mousedown as part of the dragging process. Flash does this as well. Put a textfield in a movieclip to make it draggable and you can no longer edit it.

Comment: @Vanwaril I believe this is a bug in the browsers, because when you click on the editable element it neither allows you to edit the content nor to drag the parent element!

Answer (score 4):

It makes sense that the `draggable` and `contenteditable` properties would collide.  `contenteditable` elements, like any text field, will focus on mousedown (not click).  `draggable` elements operate based on mousemove, but so does **selecting text** in a contenteditable element, so how would the browser determine whether you are trying to drag the element or select text?  Since the properties can't coexist on the same element, it appears that you need a javascript solution.

Try adding these two attributes to your anchor tag:

```
onfocus="this.parentNode.draggable = false;"
onblur="this.parentNode.draggable = true;"
```

That works for me if I add it to the `<a>` tags in your jsFiddle. You could also use jQuery if it's more complicated than getting the parentNode.

Comment: On the other hand, I would expect one to take priority over the other; either `draggable` to cause clicks on the child to allow it to be dragged, or `contenteditable` causes clicks on the child to be edit clicks, and drag doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This is a workaround since I believe the inability for these two functionalities to work together resides in the HTML spec itself (i.e. the *not working together* thing is intentional since the browser can't determine whether you want to focus or drag on the mousedown event)**

---

I noticed you explicitly set 'no libraries', so I will provide a raw javascript/HTML5 answer

http://jsfiddle.net/4rdpV/26/

This was my crack at it.

First of all, it might be better to include the data in one single localStorage item, rather than scatter it.

```
storage={
    '1.text':'test 1',
    '2.text':'test 2'
}
if(localStorage['test']){
    storage=JSON.parse(localStorage['test'])
}
```

this creates that ability, using JSON to convert between object and string. Objects can indeed be nested

I also added `(edit)` links next to the items, when clicked, these links will transform the items into `input` elements, so you can edit the text. After hitting enter, it transforms it back and saves the data. At the same time, the list items remain draggable.

After saving, hit F12 in chrome, find the console, and look in the localStorage object, you will see all the data was saved in `localStorage['test']` as an Object using `JSON.stringify()`

I tried my best to design this to be scaleable, and I think I succeeded well enough; you just need to replace  the HTML with a container and use a javascript for loop to write out several items, using the iterator of your choice to fill the parameter for `edit()`. For example:

Say you changed storage to hold "paradigms" of lists, and you have one called "shopping list". And say the storage object looks something like this:

```
{
    "shopping list":{
         1:"Milk",
         2:"Eggs",
         3:"Bread"
    }
}
```

This could render that list out:

```
for(i in storage['shopping list']){
    _item = storage['shopping list'][i];
    container.innerHTML+='<li draggable=true><a id="item'+i+'">'+_item+'</a><a href="#" onclick="edit('+i+')"> (edit)</a></li>'
}
```

Of course, if you were to edit the structure of the storage object, you would need to edit the functions as well.

The output would look something like this:

```
Milk (edit)
Eggs (edit)
Bread (edit)
```

Don't worry about the input elements if that worries you; CSS can easily fix it to look like it didn't just change.

If you don't want the `(edit)` links to be visible, for example, you can do this in CSS:

```
a[href="#"]{
    display:none;
}
li[draggable="true"]:hover a[href="#"]{
    display:inline;
}
```

Now the edit links will only appear when you hover the mouse over the list item, like this version:

http://jsfiddle.net/4rdpV/27/

---

I hope this answer helped.

Comment: Okay, I checked the localStorage myself, and it turns out JSFiddle  has managed to sandbox that as well. I don't know how they pulled that off, but trying `localStorage` in the console returns an empty storage object. So nevermind that line about checking the `localStorage` unless you have your project in an .html file.

Comment: @Vanwaril I guess I should have noted that it's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Using html5sortable and newer JQuery events (delegate is deprecated, answer 3 years after initial question), bug still affects Chrome 37.  Contenteditable spans and html5sortable seem to play nice in other browsers.  I know this is only partially relevant, just keeping documentation on changes I've noticed.

```
$(document).on('focus', 'li span[contenteditable]', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().sortable('destroy'); // removes sortable from the whole parent UL
});

$(document).on('blur', 'li span[contenteditable]', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().sortable({ connectWith: '.sortable' }); // re-adds sortable to the parent UL
});
```