# Why the div whose parent is draggable, loses its contenteditable attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a child div whose parent div is draggable with content-editable set to true. I am using jQuery UI to make its parent div to be draggable but the child div loses its contenteditable attribute.

My question is why that child div is showing this kind of behaviour?

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
```

[***Fiddle Link***](http://jsfiddle.net/Va8gh/4/)

Comment: Actually it's not loosing contenteditability, just click the `div` with middle- or right button and you'll see. It seems that jQuery prevents default action when clicking with left button.

Comment: yeah when i click with right button, it is editable but what is the solution for it? need to edit jQuery UI?

Comment: Please have a look here maybe this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399131/html5-draggable-and-contenteditable-not-working-together

Comment: hey i don't think so that i found a valid solution because nothing is working! i think i should add this question to bounty after 2 days!

Comment: @Teemu Yes, there was something goes wrong when I was adding the comment

Comment: @AspiringAqib Can't the idea from Hrant Khachatrian`s answer be applied to your case? Modified code might just save you some rep : ).

Comment: @Teemu, no its not working if you can solute my question then u can add it as answer and i will accept that :D i just want that parent to `draggable` and child div to be `contenteditable`

Comment: cant' you put back the attribute using one of draggable available callback?

Comment: thanks everybody for just helping me! salute to you all bro :D

Comment: @AspiringAqib I was strugling with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tpgL/2/), maybe it's not exactly what you need. If you've found a solution, please post it as an answer, it might be useful for future visitors too, (at least I'm very interested : ).

Comment: @Teemu salute to you sir :D you are invited to post it as answer. Your solution works as expected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if editing and dragging can occur together. Anyway, you can cancel dragging when clicking on the editable area:

```
$(".editable").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return;
});
```

To enlarge draggable area, you need to shrink editable one, something like this:

```
.editable {
    max-width:190px;
    height:20px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    padding:1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

A working demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tpgL/2/).

Comment: good work but i got way way better solution than this one buddy :D but this solution fits what i asked!

Comment: @Muhammad - Stackoverflow is about give and take. Why don't you publish your "way better" solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution: 
 $(`. draggable`).draggable()
            .click(function() {
        $(this).draggable({disabled: true});
    })
            .blur(function() {
        $(this).draggable({disabled: false});
    });