# Why does making a div draggable kill the contenteditable feature?

Tags: jquery-ui

In this example -  http://jsfiddle.net/k9tPA/2/ - I have two divs where I've set contenteditable=true.  This works fine - you can click in either box to bring the focus there, enter new text, double-click to select text, etc. But if you uncomment the line (shown below) that makes Box 1 draggable, Box 1 is no longer editable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  //  $('#Box1').draggable();
})
```

What's going on here?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like mouse events to the target are being suppressed (to avoid undesirable behavior). This is preventing most edit actions from occurring with the mouse, but you can actually hit CTRL+A and CTRL+B (select all, then bold) to see that the element is indeed still content editable. You may need to edit the draggable source to change this behavior.

Comment: Duplicate: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399131/html5-draggable-and-contenteditable-not-working-together

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317128/how-to-make-a-div-contenteditable-and-draggable

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954994/how-can-i-enable-draggable-on-a-element-with-contenteditable

And many more.