# Putting elements into a ContentEditable div that cannot be removed

Tags: javascript, html

Say you have a div like so:

```
<div contenteditable="true" droppable="true" id="editor">
    <span draggable="true" contenteditable="false" id="tag-0">0</span>
    This
    <span draggable="true" contenteditable="false" id="tag-1">1</span>
    will be the editor.
</div>
```

The two spans "tag-0" and "tag-1"  represent tags that should be interspersed among the text of the div.  The user should be able to drag them around, but **not delete them**.  Is there a good way to make that happen?

Comment: you can try to intercept the del key and cut events, but there's no easy way. Might just be easiest to poll or use a mutation event and inject them if missing.

Comment: How about wrapping the editable portions in editable elements instead of making the entire div editable? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7DBQ/)

Comment: Just an extra note. `contenteditable` and `draggable` do not play nicely together. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399131/html5-draggable-and-contenteditable-not-working-together

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve but looks like you can use JQuery's draggable functionality.

Here is a link. http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Play with the demo first to see if it what you want. If it is then great as it is easy to do with JQuery.